# how to insert city state and zip code to android contact using intent?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contacts

I am trying to insert a contact using Intent to the android directory, where i have the name number and city state an zip code. but all other fields are getting inserted except for CITY STATE and ZIP CODE.

i tried using below code but nothing works. Please help. i tried reading couple of post where it state that we cannot add city state. i hope there would be some tweak to get this done.

```
            putExtra(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY,
                "employeeData.cityName"
            )
            putExtra(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION,
                "employeeData.state"
            )
            putExtra(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE,
                "employeeData.zipCode"
            )
```